# Calling nested dicts in dart

Tags: dart

I would like to use nested dicts in flutter and therefore I need to know, how to call them in dart. I created a dictionary, that
has as its last entry a sub-dictionary.

```
void main() {
  var subdict = {'a':'Samba','b':'Tango','c':'FoxTrott','d':'Waltz'};
  
  var diction = {'1':'Alpha','2':'Beta','3':'Gamma','4':subdict};
  
  print(diction['4']);
}
```

Calling this dictionary with `diction['4']` is easy, but how do I call e.g. 'Tango' of the subdict?

```
diction['4']['a']
```

does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the Dart type system cannot make sense of your code. Dart will try to guess the type of:

```
var diction = {'1':'Alpha','2':'Beta','3':'Gamma','4':subdict};
```

Since there are multiple types of objects in the map, it will try to find the common class for all of them. In this case this line will be compiled into:

```
Map<String, Object> diction = {'1':'Alpha','2':'Beta','3':'Gamma','4':subdict};
```

The compiler will then see the following code:

```
diction['4']['a']
```

Since the values of the map is of the type `Object`, the compiler can only guess the type of `diction['4']` must be `Object`. Since `Object` does not have a `[]` operator, the code will fail at compile time.

If you want to tell the compiler it should not care about static analysis of the types before the code are running, you can set the type of the values in the map to `dynamic` like:

```
var diction = <String, dynamic>{'1':'Alpha','2':'Beta','3':'Gamma','4':subdict};
```

By doing so, it will be determined on runtime if there are any problems with the code.  But you are also loosing the features of the strong type system every time you are using `dynamic` with the risk of creating code where type problems can only be found on runtime.

Comment: Thank you, do you recommend putting also 'Alpha','Beta',... as (single-element) subdicts into the dict?

Comment: If you want the type system to understand your code, then yes, I would recommend to make the type simpler by being consistent of the type of objects you put into the map.

Comment: Does the same hold true for nested lists like    
                    
 ```var sublist = ["100","101","102","103","104"]; ```
  and
  ```var listi   = <Int, dynamic> ["1","2","3","4","5",sublist];```?

Comment: ``<Int, dynamic> ["1","2","3","4","5",sublist]` this does not make sense since you have defined a `List` which only contains values and no keys. But yes, your List contains both `String` and `List<String>` so same problem here.

Comment: Instead of using `dynamic` you can also just let the type system assign the type `List<Object>` and then you make a type cast every time you try access an element like `list[3] as String`. The type cast will then fail at runtime if the type is not correct. But this does not change the fact you are getting runtime exceptions instead of have a data model where the type system can help you.